# Always get error when read file input from form in view

Tags: php, forms, laravel, upload

In there i using two input file, one hidden and one visible, here I want to try how to call the input to the controller, but has an error **Call to a member function getRealPath() on null** , how to call the input file which is hidden in the form. Thanks for your answer

here in controller script :

```
public function postPhoto()
    {
        $photo = Input::file('photo')->getRealPath();

        if($this->cekUkuranFoto($photo) == false)
        {
            Session::flash('message', 'size too big 2048 x 2048 !');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
}
public function cekUkuranFoto($file)
    {
        $gambar = Image::make($file);
        $ukuran = getimagesize($file);
        $width=$ukuran[0];
        $height=$ukuran[1];

        if($width < 2048 && height < 2048)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

here form on view :

```
<form method="GET" action="{!! URL::to('/timeline/photo') !!}" files="true" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <input name='photo' id="file-image" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
                    <p class="help-block">Maksimal ukuran foto 1500 x 1000 pixel</p>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img id="image-responsive" class="img-responsive img-bordered-sm" src="{!! url('/').'/protected/public/assets/images/default.png' !!}" height=128 alt="your image"/><br/>
                    <input name="photo2" type="button" id="my-button" class ="btn btn-info" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" value="Pilih Foto">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="hapusGambar()" >Hapus</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <textarea name="photoinput" class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Deskripsi">{!! Input::old('photoinput') !!}</textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-footer">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Posting</button>
                </div>
                </form>
```

in route :

```
Route::get('/timeline/photo', 'ClientTimeLineContr@postPhoto' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not work with `GET` method:

```
method="GET"
```

you should change it for `POST`. Your route also:

```
Route::post('/timeline/photo', 'ClientTimeLineContr@postPhoto' );
```